# Get module exports from an async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle

in the module async.js I'm have three SQL queries stored in the asyncTasks array. In the async.parallel function the result is published with console.log(results) and everything looks fine. BUT how can I pass this result back to main.js from where I called this module with var as = async.getExtradata();. I think, the problem is, that when I want to return response in async.js, the async.parallel function is not finished. How can I handle this?

```
// async.js:
var response = [];

function getExradata(reqq, ress){
    oracledb.getConnection(
        config,
        function (err, connection) {
            if (err) { console.error(err.message); return; }
            var asyncTasks = [];
            var items = ['1234','3215','2306'];

            items.forEach(function(item){
                asyncTasks.push(function(callback){
                    connection.execute(
                        "SELECT * FROM mde.mobile_blgkopf WHERE blg_id = 
                         '"+item+"'",
                        [],
                        {
                            outFormat: oracledb.OBJECT
                        },
                        function (err, result) {
                            if (err) {                                   
                                return;
                            }
                            callback(null, result.rows);
                        });
                });
            });
            async.parallel(asyncTasks,
                function(err, results) {
                    console.log(results);
                    response = results;                       
                });
        });
    return response;
};
module.exports.getExtradata = getExradata;


// main.js:
var async = require(__dirname + '/async.js');
var as = async.getExtradata();
```

Comment: `response` will be filled later, since it's async, return a `Promise` instead.

Comment: I read about Promises but I still can't figure out how to use it in my code. Can you give me an example please?

Comment: Here is an example for your code: http://jsfiddle.net/gqejmbo8/

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that a connection can only do one thing at a time. So even though you're using `async.parallel`, the queries will still be executed one at a time (your code just obfuscates that fact). Even worse, you will likely use more background threads than intended (basically locking them as they wait for the ones in front to finish). This will prevent your application from scaling and lead to hard to track down bugs. Don't use async.parallel with node-oracledb in this way.

Also, you're using string concatenation with the values in the query. This will likely open you up to SQL injection and performance issues. Make sure to use bind variables instead. https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#-18-bind-parameters-for-prepared-statements

When it comes to performance, round trips and data transfer are often the biggest issues. Although the data transfer can't be avoided here, you could get the data in a single round trip.

Here's an example that uses async/await, bind variables, and a single round trip.

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const config = require('./dbConfig.js');

async function runTest() {
  let conn;

  try {
    // These values would come from the user
    const group1Id = 30;
    const group2Id = 50;
    const group3Id = 80;

    conn = await oracledb.getConnection(config);

    // First get the data using a single round trip and bind variables.
    const result = await conn.execute(
     `select * 
      from employees 
      where department_id in (:group1, :group2, :group3)`,
      {
        group1: group1Id,
        group2: group2Id,
        group3: group3Id
      },
      {
        outFormat: oracledb.OBJECT
      }
    );

    // Now that we have ALL the data, we can split it up into the buckets
    // we need. There are lots of different ways you could do this, this
    // is just one example.
    const empsInGroup1 = [];
    const empsInGroup2 = [];
    const empsInGroup3 = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i += 1) {
      switch (result.rows[i].DEPARTMENT_ID) {
        case group1Id:
          empsInGroup1.push(result.rows[i]);
          break;
        case group2Id:
          empsInGroup2.push(result.rows[i]);
          break;
        case group3Id:
          empsInGroup3.push(result.rows[i]);
          break;
      }
    }

    console.log(empsInGroup1.length); // 6
    console.log(empsInGroup2.length); // 45
    console.log(empsInGroup3.length); // 34
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (conn) {
      try {
        await conn.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}

runTest();
```

Of course, that wasn't what you really asked. :) To learn more about async timing with respect to HTTP APIs, database logic, and various other modules, see this series on creating a REST API: https://jsao.io/2018/03/creating-a-rest-api-with-node-js-and-oracle-database/

Comment: That's a very helpful answer, thank you! My problem is, that I have many complex oracle procedures given from my company and I find it very hard to suit my needs. This procedure I'm calling is actually:

Comment: Stephan, did you see my other question? Are you running an anonymous block or a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your great answer DanMcGhan, you helped me a lot. I'm very new in Oracle/SQL and actually I'm calling a PL/SQL procedure given from my company and not just a simple SELECT statement. I find it very hard to suit my needs. Don't know if I should open a new thread for this but I think the context is important. The procedure that gives me the values is this:

```
BEGIN

    SELECT Nvl(Sum(loat_mg),0)
      INTO v_best_lag
      FROM unitrade.loa
    WHERE loa_at_at_se_se_ag_ag_wg = v_ber
       AND loa_at_at_se_se_ag_ag_no = v_wgr
       AND loa_at_at_se_se_no       = v_agr
       AND loa_at_at_no             = v_art
       AND loat_zen = v_fil;

    SELECT Sum(LOAT_MG * stzu_mg)
      INTO v_best_lagkombi
      from unitrade.stz
      join unitrade.loa
        on LOA_AT_AT_SE_SE_AG_AG_WG = stz_st_at_se_se_ag_ag_wg
       AND LOA_AT_AT_SE_SE_AG_AG_NO = stz_st_at_se_se_ag_ag_no
       AND LOA_AT_AT_SE_SE_NO       = stz_st_at_se_se_no
       AND LOA_AT_AT_NO             = stz_st_at_no
    WHERE stz_at_at_se_se_ag_ag_wg = v_ber
       AND stz_at_at_se_se_ag_ag_no = v_wgr
       AND stz_at_at_se_se_no       = v_agr
       AND stz_at_at_no             = v_art
       AND LOAT_ZEN                 = v_fil;

    SELECT Nvl(Sum(bstd_resmg),0)
      INTO v_off_aek
      FROM bst_bsd_view
    WHERE bsd_at_at_se_se_ag_ag_wg     = v_ber
       AND bsd_at_at_se_se_ag_ag_no     = v_wgr
       AND bsd_at_at_se_se_no     = v_agr
       AND bsd_at_at_no     = v_art
       AND bstd_zen = v_fil;

END;
```

as you can see, the procedure returns values for one item and the ID of the item consists of five values(ber,wgr,agr,art,fil). So how can I change this procedure so it gives me one row per item and the values as columns? 
PS: I read many articles on your website (jsao.io) and it helped me a lot at the beginning of my work. But now I'm stucked

Comment: We call the code you showed above an anonymous block, which is analogous to an anonymous function in JavaScript. Anonymous blocks are generally passed from the client (Node.js in this case) to the database for execution. On the other hand, stored procedures, functions, and packages have names and are stored in the database. These are called by name from clients. Which are you working with? Once I know that I'll mock something up for you.

Comment: I'm running a stored procedure, which is saved in an oracle DB. In node I'm just calling the procedure with the SQL-Statement "BEGIN procedure_name(:param1,param2); END;" so the result is passed back to node

Answer (score 0):

TLDR The driver doesn't currently work with complex data structures (user-defined types and PL/SQL records), but it can work with simple arrays (number, varchar2, and date). In your case, you can send in an array of ids for which you need related data and populate out binds with the data. The id array is in/out because there's no guarantee the order of the arrays will match what was sent in (unless you do that yourself).

I'm using a package rather than a stand-alone procedure so I can declare an array type.

Given the following package:

```
create or replace package my_pkg
as

type number_aat is table of number
  index by pls_integer;

procedure get_vals(
  p_dept_ids     in out number_aat,
  p_emp_counts   out number_aat,
  p_sum_salaries out number_aat
);

end my_pkg;
/

create or replace package body my_pkg
as

procedure get_vals(
  p_dept_ids     in out number_aat,
  p_emp_counts   out number_aat,
  p_sum_salaries out number_aat
)

is

  -- Use an existing varray type so you do not have to create one
  l_number_list sys.odcinumberlist := sys.odcinumberlist();

begin

  -- Extend the varray to match the number of elements in p_dept_ids
  l_number_list.extend(p_dept_ids.count);

  -- Populate the varray with the values from p_dept_ids
  for x in 1 .. p_dept_ids.count
  loop
    l_number_list(x) := p_dept_ids(x);
  end loop;

  -- Populate the out binds (associative arrays) with the data
  select department_id, 
    count(*), 
    sum(salary)
  bulk collect into p_dept_ids, 
    p_emp_counts, 
    p_sum_salaries
  from employees
  where department_id in (
    select column_value
    from table(l_number_list)
  )
  group by department_id;

end get_vals;

end my_pkg;
/
```

The following should work:

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const config = require('./dbConfig.js');

async function runTest() {
  let conn;

  try {
    const deptIdsFromEndUser = [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80];
    conn = await oracledb.getConnection(config);

    const result = await conn.execute(
     `begin

        my_pkg.get_vals(:dept_ids, :emp_counts, :sum_salaries);

      end;`,
      {
        dept_ids: {
          dir: oracledb.BIND_INOUT,
          type: oracledb.NUMBER,
          val: deptIdsFromEndUser,
          maxArraySize: 100
        },
        emp_counts: {
          dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT,
          type: oracledb.NUMBER,
          maxArraySize: 100
        },
        sum_salaries: {
          dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT,
          type: oracledb.NUMBER,
          maxArraySize: 100
        }
      }
    );

    // Now that we have the values in JS we can do what we need to with them.
    console.log(result.outBinds);

    // { dept_ids: [ 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 ],
    //   emp_counts: [ 2, 6, 1, 45, 5, 1, 34 ],
    //   sum_salaries: [ 19000, 24900, 6500, 156400, 28800, 10000, 304500 ] }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (conn) {
      try {
        await conn.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}

runTest();
```

Comment: The change I want to make: I have not just one "p_dept_id" but one hundreds of them. And of course I don't want to fire 100 single requests to the server. So I think I must pass an array of IDs to the procedure, but it's not so easy. Or can I write all IDs in the "p_dept_id", seperated by commas and the procedure loops through all IDs?

Comment: I've updated the answer to more accurately reflect your situation. Let me know if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a new answer that I hope more closely aligns with your use case. I'm still trying to keep you working in sets rather than getting into row by row situations.

Given the following objects (you can run these to recreate the objects):

```
-- Create a parent table and populate it.
create table t1 (
  id1 number not null,
  id2 number not null,
  id3 number not null,
  id4 number not null,
  val1 number,
  constraint t_u1 unique (id1, id2, id3, id4)
);

insert into t1 (id1, id2, id3, id4, val1) values (1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
insert into t1 (id1, id2, id3, id4, val1) values (1, 1, 1, 2, 2);
insert into t1 (id1, id2, id3, id4, val1) values (1, 1, 2, 1, 3);
insert into t1 (id1, id2, id3, id4, val1) values (1, 1, 2, 2, 4);
insert into t1 (id1, id2, id3, id4, val1) values (1, 2, 1, 1, 5);
insert into t1 (id1, id2, id3, id4, val1) values (1, 2, 1, 2, 6);
insert into t1 (id1, id2, id3, id4, val1) values (1, 2, 2, 1, 7);
insert into t1 (id1, id2, id3, id4, val1) values (1, 2, 2, 2, 8);
insert into t1 (id1, id2, id3, id4, val1) values (2, 1, 1, 1, 9);
insert into t1 (id1, id2, id3, id4, val1) values (2, 1, 1, 2, 10);
insert into t1 (id1, id2, id3, id4, val1) values (2, 1, 2, 1, 11);
insert into t1 (id1, id2, id3, id4, val1) values (2, 1, 2, 2, 12);
insert into t1 (id1, id2, id3, id4, val1) values (2, 2, 1, 1, 13);
insert into t1 (id1, id2, id3, id4, val1) values (2, 2, 1, 2, 14);
insert into t1 (id1, id2, id3, id4, val1) values (2, 2, 2, 1, 15);
insert into t1 (id1, id2, id3, id4, val1) values (2, 2, 2, 2, 16);

-- Create a child table and populate it.
create table t2 (
  id1 number not null,
  id2 number not null,
  id3 number not null,
  id4 number not null,
  val1 number(,0),
  val2 number,
  foreign key (id1, id2, id3, id4)
    references t1 (id1, id2, id3, id4)
);

insert into t2
select round(dbms_random.value(1,2)),
  round(dbms_random.value(1,2)),
  round(dbms_random.value(1,2)),
  round(dbms_random.value(1,2)),
  round(dbms_random.value(1,100)),
  round(dbms_random.value(1,100))
from dual
connect by rownum <= 1000;

-- Delete some data from the child table so that not every
-- primary key combination has a match.
delete from t2
where id1 = 1
  and id2 = 2
  and id3 = 2
  and id4 = 1;

delete from t2
where id1 = 2
  and id2 = 2
  and id3 = 2
  and id4 = 1;

-- Create a temp table to demonstrate another way to get
-- the values in SQL.
create global temporary table id_values(
  id1 number,
  id2 number,
  id3 number,
  id4 number
) on commit delete rows;

create or replace package my_pkg
as

type number_aat is table of number
  index by pls_integer;

type varchar2_aat is table of varchar2(256)
  index by pls_integer;

procedure get_vals(
  p_id1_vals    in out number_aat,
  p_id2_vals    in out number_aat,
  p_id3_vals    in out number_aat,
  p_id4_vals    in out number_aat,
  p_parent_uks  out varchar2_aat,
  p_parent_sums out number_aat,
  p_child_uks   out varchar2_aat,
  p_child_sums  out number_aat,
  p_child_avgs  out number_aat
);

end my_pkg;
/

create or replace package body my_pkg
as

procedure get_vals(
  p_id1_vals    in out number_aat,
  p_id2_vals    in out number_aat,
  p_id3_vals    in out number_aat,
  p_id4_vals    in out number_aat,
  p_parent_uks  out varchar2_aat,
  p_parent_sums out number_aat,
  p_child_uks   out varchar2_aat,
  p_child_sums  out number_aat,
  p_child_avgs  out number_aat
)

is

begin

  if not p_id1_vals.count = p_id2_vals.count
    and p_id1_vals.count = p_id3_vals.count
    and p_id1_vals.count = p_id4_vals.count
  then
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'ID arrays must have the same number of elements');
  end if;

  -- Move the ids from the arrays passed into the temporary table
  -- so they can be accessed via SQL
  forall idx in 1 .. p_id1_vals.count
    insert into id_values (id1, id2, id3, id4)
      values (p_id1_vals(idx), p_id2_vals(idx), p_id3_vals(idx), p_id4_vals(idx));

  select id1 || ':' || id2 || ':'  || id3 || ':' || id4 as ids_as_string,
    sum(val1)
  bulk collect into p_parent_uks,
    p_parent_sums 
  from t1
  where (id1, id2, id3, id4) in (
    select id1, id2, id3, id4
    from id_values
  )
  group by id1, 
    id2,
    id3,
    id4;

  select id1 || ':' || id2 || ':'  || id3 || ':' || id4 as ids_as_string,
    sum(val1),
    round(avg(val2))
  bulk collect into p_child_uks,
    p_child_sums,
    p_child_avgs 
  from t2
  where (id1, id2, id3, id4) in (
    select id1, id2, id3, id4
    from id_values
  )
  group by id1,
    id2,
    id3,
    id4;

end get_vals;

end my_pkg;
/
```

The following should work...

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const config = require('./dbConfig.js');

async function runTest() {
  let conn;

  try {
    // These values would come from an end user
    const id1Vals = [1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1];
    const id2Vals = [2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1];
    const id3Vals = [2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2];
    const id4Vals = [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1];

    conn = await oracledb.getConnection(config);

    const result = await conn.execute(
     `begin

        my_pkg.get_vals(
          :id1_vals, 
          :id2_vals, 
          :id3_vals, 
          :id4_vals, 
          :parent_uks, 
          :parent_sums, 
          :child_uks, 
          :child_sums, 
          :child_avgs
        );

      end;`,
      {
        id1_vals: {
          dir: oracledb.BIND_IN,
          type: oracledb.NUMBER,
          val: id1Vals,
          maxArraySize: 100
        },
        id2_vals: {
          dir: oracledb.BIND_IN,
          type: oracledb.NUMBER,
          val: id2Vals,
          maxArraySize: 100
        },
        id3_vals: {
          dir: oracledb.BIND_IN,
          type: oracledb.NUMBER,
          val: id3Vals,
          maxArraySize: 100
        },
        id4_vals: {
          dir: oracledb.BIND_IN,
          type: oracledb.NUMBER,
          val: id4Vals,
          maxArraySize: 100
        },
        parent_uks: {
          dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT,
          type: oracledb.STRING,
          maxArraySize: 100
        },
        parent_sums: {
          dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT,
          type: oracledb.NUMBER,
          maxArraySize: 100
        },
        child_uks: {
          dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT,
          type: oracledb.STRING,
          maxArraySize: 100
        },
        child_sums: {
          dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT,
          type: oracledb.NUMBER,
          maxArraySize: 100
        },
        child_avgs: {
          dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT,
          type: oracledb.NUMBER,
          maxArraySize: 100
        }
      }
    );

    // Now that we have the values in JS we can do what we need to with them.
    console.log(result.outBinds);

    // Create a new object to hold the reformatted results.
    const reformattedResults = {};

    // Ensure that there's on property for each primary key combination requested.
    for (let x = 0; x < id1Vals.length; x += 1) {
      let idAsString = `${id1Vals[x]}:${id2Vals[x]}:${id3Vals[x]}:${id4Vals[x]}`;
      reformattedResults[idAsString] = {};
    }

    // Populate the appropriate property with the correct values from the parent
    // table.
    for (let x = 0; x < result.outBinds.parent_uks.length; x += 1) {
      reformattedResults[result.outBinds.parent_uks[x]].parentSum = result.outBinds.parent_sums[x];
    }

    // Populate the appropriate property with the correct values from the child
    // table.
    for (let x = 0; x < result.outBinds.child_uks.length; x += 1) {
      reformattedResults[result.outBinds.child_uks[x]].childSum = result.outBinds.child_sums[x];
      reformattedResults[result.outBinds.child_uks[x]].childAvg = result.outBinds.child_avgs[x];
    }

    console.log(reformattedResults);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (conn) {
      try {
        await conn.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}

runTest();
```

I created separate "id out binds", one for each table that I was accessing, since I might not always get a hit. Your data is likely different so you might take a different approach (like joining to a fact table to ensure rows exist).

As always, there are lots of different approaches you can take. Hopefully, you're starting to see some options that will work for you.